# how to use php file_exist in twig opencart

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

In, **Opencart** framework version - 3

How can I implement php function `FILE_EXIST` in `Twig`?

Comment: What exactly you want to do??

Comment: `<?php if(file_exists("catalog/view/theme/$templatepath/stylesheet/stylesheet.min.css")){ ?>`

I want to use above line of code in twig.

Comment: You can also check that from server side and pass a flag variable (which contains either true or false) to twig file and based on that include the css.

Comment: Is there any way to directly implement it in twig file rather than write code in controller?

Comment: i think there is not any way to do this.you need to write code in controller

Comment: `file_exists` is not a default function that exists inside `twig`

Comment: You could add a new `Twig_Simple_Function` if you are able to locate the `twig` instance. `$twig->addFilter(new \Twig_Simple_Function', 'file_exists', 'file_exists'));`